# text to column many excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to perform text to column on many workbooks using vba.

I tried the below code but it's working on only one workbook while i want all of them to be modified except the "Testmac" wb.

```
Sub sdptest()

Dim w As Workbook

For Each w In Workbooks
If w.Name <> "testmac" Then

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select

End If
Next w    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `Columns("A:A")` implicitly reference `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A")`,
That's why it was working on only one sheet!

Here is the code to do it in all opened workbooks, on all sheets :

Note that I have commented the part that deletes the column (which seems strange after putting the data there), so just uncomment it if you need! ;)

```
Sub sdptest()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet

For Each w In Workbooks
    If InStr(1, LCase(w.Name), "testmac") Then
    Else
        For Each wS In w.Sheets
            With wS.Columns("A:A")
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then
                    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
                                DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                                Tab:=False, _
                                Semicolon:=False, _
                                Comma:=True, _
                                Space:=False, _
                                Other:=False, _
                                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
                    '.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                Else
                End If
            End With 'wS.Columns("A:A")
        Next wS
    End If
Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for this quick reply, when i ran the code an error occured: "No data was selected to parse". Kindly help

Comment: @h.barry : try the edit! I guess that it found an empty sheet, so I've added a test! ;)

Comment: @h.barry : Glad I could help! ;)